# How to persist an entity as Json in MySql?

Tags: java, mysql, json, spring, hibernate

I'm using `spring` and `hibernate` to persist  `@Entity` classes into a `mysql` database.

For one attribute, I want to persist the object as a `String` or `Json` field, rather than creating an additional table and using `@OneToOne` reference mappings or similar.

Take the following just as an example:

```
@Entity
public class Customer {

    //@JsonObject
    private List<Address> address;
}

public class Address {
    private String street, number, city, zip, country;
}
```

Question: how could I tell hibernate to automatically save that address as string/json? And of course, when reading the string/json should be remapped into an Address object.

Comment: You can try writing a custom serializer for the same or save that into a json type in database itself (details in answer)

Comment: Worth checking https://stackoverflow.com/a/59942878/1776132

Answer (score 0):

You can store jsons into mySQL tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `book` (
  `id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `tags` json DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Insert query:

```
INSERT INTO `book` (`title`, `tags`)
VALUES (
  'ECMAScript 2015: A SitePoint Anthology',
  '["JavaScript", "ES2015", "JSON"]'
);
```

In hibernate, you should create class (like "com.test.MyJsonType") that must implement org.hibernate.usertype. UserType interface where the nullSafeGet method should deserialize JSON to java object (using Jackson), the nullSafeSet serialize POJO to JSON and some other auxiliary methods.

Comment: Isn't there a simpler method, than having to implement a `UserType` interface that requires like 10 methods to be implemented on its own?

Comment: Would you like to implement a serializer and de-serializer for that field and then store that same as a string?

Comment: Found a library here: https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-json-objects-using-generic-hibernate-types/

Comment: Maybe, I'm already using `Jackson` (de)serializer as for the webservice endpoint. So you think I should just save the entity as a serialized string, and deserialize manually?

Answer (score 0):

For the moment I could solve it with `AttributesConverter`. Nice that `Spring` can automatically inject the jackson mapper into it:

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
    @Convert(converter = AddressConverter.class)
    @Lob
    @Column(columnDefinition = "text")
    private List<Address> address;
}

@Converter
public class AddressConverter implements AttributeConverter<List<Address>, String> {
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired //injected by spring
    public AddressConverter(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(List<AddressConverter> list) {
        try {
            if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(list))
                return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(list);
        } catch (final JsonProcessingException e) {
            LOGGER.error(e);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Address> convertToEntityAttribute(String json) {
        try {
            if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(json))
                return objectMapper.readValue(json, List.class);
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error(e);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```